# c++ function outputs differently when run from a arm device vs a x64 machine

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, arm, byte, sizeof

I am trying to a c++ python so that converts a image into CbCrA, but the same function outputs two different outputs when run from a raspberry pi and a ubuntu laptop. I know that there are variables that have a different size on arm but im not able to pin point what messing it up though.

```
static PyObject *
method_rgb_to_atem(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    Py_buffer input_buffer;
    Py_ssize_t data_length;
    unsigned int width, height, premultiply;
    PyObject *res;

    /* Parse arguments */
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "y*IIp", &input_buffer, &width, &height, &premultiply)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    data_length = input_buffer.len;
    unsigned char *buffer;
    buffer = input_buffer.buf;

    char *outbuffer = (char *) malloc(data_length);
    if (outbuffer == NULL) {
        return PyErr_NoMemory();
    }

    char *writepointer = outbuffer;

    int pixel_size = 8;
    for (int i = 0; i < data_length; i += pixel_size) {
        // Convert RGBA 8888 to 10-bit BT.709 Y'CbCrA
        float r1 = (float)buffer[0] / 255;
        float g1 = (float)buffer[1] / 255;
        float b1 = (float)buffer[2] / 255;
        float r2 = (float)buffer[4] / 255;
        float g2 = (float)buffer[5] / 255;
        float b2 = (float)buffer[6] / 255;

        if (premultiply) {
            // PNG files have straight alpha, for BMD switchers premultipled alpha is easier
            float a1 = (float)buffer[3] / 255;
            float a2 = (float)buffer[7] / 255;
            r1 = r1 * a1;
            g1 = g1 * a1;
            b1 = b1 * a1;
            r2 = r2 * a2;
            g2 = g2 * a2;
            b2 = b2 * a2;
        }

        float y1 = (0.2126 * r1) + (0.7152 * g1) + (0.0722 * b1);
        float y2 = (0.2126 * r2) + (0.7152 * g2) + (0.0722 * b2);
        float cb = (b2 - y2) / 1.8556;
        float cr = (r2 - y2) /  1.5748;

        unsigned short a10a = ((buffer[3] << 2) * 219 / 255) + (15 << 2) + 1;
        unsigned short a10b = ((buffer[7] << 2) * 219 / 255) + (15 << 2) + 1;
        unsigned short y10a = clamp((unsigned short)(y1 * 876) + 64, 64, 940);
        unsigned short y10b = clamp((unsigned short)(y2 * 876) + 64, 64, 940);
        unsigned short cb10 = clamp((unsigned short)(cb * 896) + 512, 44, 960);
        unsigned short cr10 = clamp((unsigned short)(cr * 896) + 512, 44, 960);

        writepointer[0] = (unsigned char) (a10a >> 4);
        writepointer[1] = (unsigned char) (((a10a & 0x0f) << 4) | (cb10 >> 6));
        writepointer[2] = (unsigned char) (((cb10 & 0x3f) << 2) | (y10a >> 8));
        writepointer[3] = (unsigned char) (y10a & 0xff);
        writepointer[4] = (unsigned char) (a10b >> 4);
        writepointer[5] = (unsigned char) (((a10b & 0x0f) << 4) | (cr10 >> 6));
        writepointer[6] = (unsigned char) (((cr10 & 0x3f) << 2) | (y10b >> 8));
        writepointer[7] = (unsigned char) (y10b & 0xff);
        writepointer += pixel_size;
        buffer += pixel_size;
    }

    res = Py_BuildValue("y#", outbuffer, data_length);
    free(outbuffer);
    return res;
}
```

On Ubuntu (22.04)
for this input `b'\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff'`
the Output is

```
b':\x96h\xfa:\x9f\x00\xfa'
```

or (hexdump)

```
00000000: 3A 96 68 FA 3A 9F 00 FA                           :.h.:...
```

On a Raspberry pi  arm32bit and 64bi (raspberry pi os)
for the same input
I get the output

```
b':\x98\x00\xfa:\x9f\x00\xfa'
```

or (hexdump)

```
00000000: 3A 98 00 FA 3A 9F 00 FA                           :...:...
```

Comment: If you [edit] your question so that it complies with Stackoverflow's requirements for [mre], so that everyone else in the world can cut/paste it, ***exactly as shown*** then compile and run it, and observe the difference themselves, then I am confident that someone will be able to figure it out. If you cannot do that, I'm confident that it's unlikely that anyone will be able to do anything.

Comment: I'd not expect that the binary  float formats are the same on different CPU architectures.

Comment: First, print the sizes of `int` and `short`. And for portability you'd better use types like `int64_t`, `int32_t` and `int16_t` instead.

Comment: Probably the easiest approach would be to output intermediate values to a trace file and then  compare the 2 files.  This should help you localise the issue(s).

Comment: The values of `y1` and `y2` may depend on the register width used for intermediate values. Also note that you're doing arithmetic with `double` and then truncating. Is that intentional?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - that is not a given for sure, but in this case they probably are, both being little-endian and having IEEE-754 FPU's.  However, even if that were not the case it has no bearing in this code, there is no bit-manipulation of the `float` variables here.

Comment: @RichardCritten. Far easier to use a debugger and inspect the variable state directly.

Comment: @Clifford depends, it's image processing so there's a lot of information.

Comment: But the error (or at least the difference) is observed with example input of just 8 bytes.  In general, writing code to debug code is a bad idea - it is just more code to get right.

Comment: I get different results again by removing the python stuff: https://godbolt.org/z/bq3ar736W (though I might have done something wrong?)

Comment: @AlanBirtles I was able to kind of pinpoint the problem (i think) ```unsigned short cb10 = std::clamp((unsigned short)(cb * 896) + 512, 44, 960);``` gives a different result on arm and x86

Comment: On a side note, it is a good idea to separate out the computation part of things like this so you can test it without all the Python machinery.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
float cb = -0.114572;
unsigned short cb10 = std::clamp((unsigned short)(cb * 896) + 512, 44, 960);
```

The arguments to `std::clamp` are deduced as `int`. `cb * 896` cast to `unsigned short` evaluates to `65434` (rather than the correct value of `-102`), adding `512` gives `65946` which then gets clamped to `960` rather than the expected value of 410. I'm guessing you meant to do this instead:

```
unsigned short cb10 = std::clamp((unsigned short)(cb * 896 + 512), 44, 960);
```

You'll then get an error that the argument types don't match, you'll either  need to cast all of your arguments to `unsigned short` or just specify the template type explicitly:

```
unsigned short cb10 = std::clamp<unsigned short>(cb * 896 + 512, 44, 960);
```

I'm not sure how your code ever worked (and I can't reproduce it working), `std::clamp<unsigned short>((unsigned short)(cb * 896 + 512), 44, 960)` does work because casting `65946` to `unsigned short` does get you back to `410` but `std::clamp` should deduce to `int` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

@AlanBirtles, Thanks for pointing it out i was able to write a custom clamp function that used float rather than short and that made the conversion happen correctly.

```
unsigned short
clamp(float v, unsigned short min, unsigned short max)
{
    const short t = v < min ? min : v;
    return t > max ? max : t;
}
```

Comment: I think `t` should probably be a `float` or at least `unsigned short` rather than `short`